# Unable to Stop Python from Flask GUI

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to create a GUI where I will have 2 buttons. Start button will trigger my python script and display the moving graph. When I press the stop button, the graph should exit and python should stop.

when I click on start button, I am getting the desired result. But it goes to infinite loop and the stop button does not exit the code.Clicking on stop button does not take the code to the decorator and my function stop() is not executed.

Below is the snippet :

```
    from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template, session
    from flask import render_template
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import io
    import threading
    import base64
    from IPython import get_ipython
    from sys import exit

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')

    @app.route('/plot' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def build_plot():
        img = io.BytesIO()
        global running
        x = np.linspace(-180, 180,1000)
        y = np.sin(x)
        global j
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        plt.plot(x[0:200], y[0:200])
        #plt.plot(x,y)
        for i in range(200, len(y)):

            plt.scatter(x[i], y[i])
            plt.pause(0.0005)


        return(get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline'))

    @app.route('/stop' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def stop():
      #stop_ind='N'
        #exit()
        return render_template('home.html')


    if __name__ == '__main__':

      app.debug = True
      app.run()
```

The function where I want to exit is not getting called.

Below is my HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <title>HOME PAGE..</title>
        <body>
            <h1>Home Page..!!</h1>
            <form action="/plot" method="POST">
      <input type="number" name="Number"  ><br> 
      <br>  
      <input type="submit" value="Start" >
      </form>

      <form action="/stop" method="POST">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Stop" >
      </form>

        </body>
    </html>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Flask app can not respond to your input because it is busy in your loop.
You will need to put the calculation of your results in a separate Thread or Coroutine in order to stop it from blocking your main Flask Thread.

Also you can use Websockets to communicate with your Frontend. Have a look at [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It uses Websockets to communicate between Flask and your Frontend.